# drupal 7 disable nolink menu item with hook

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I user Drupal 7 with superfish.

I use one menu for logged and annonymus users.

Superfish not show link to annonymus user if the page has logged in role.

But the parent  menu item has any.

So drupal show 4 nolink menu item and no children for annonymus users.

How can i disable programicaly the 4  menu item when user is not logged in?

I think about hook_menu_alter, but i don't know the url for nolink menu item.

Answer (score 0):

with Menu per role modul i can show/hide menu item / role,

http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role

It worked but they said the is not final verzion.